# javascript update via external xml or txt possible?

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, text-files

I have a javascript countdown. The first line is:

```
dateFuture1 = new Date(2011,8,21,20,30,0);
```

is it possible to update the date and time values via external text file or XML feed and if so, what would it look like?

Would something simple as

2011,8,21,20,30,0

inside a text file be possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would need some method of accessing the values within the text or XML file, but yes it is possible.  I would suggest looking into the [ajax()](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax) function within jQuery as it is fully capable of handling your request. You can also utilize JSON to help pass values to the client from the server, which in my opinion is the best way to go.